# Configuring security to access EJB through WS -- WFLYEJB0364 Connection rejected

Tags: wildfly, elytron

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/securing-ejbs-with-elytron) to configure an user `ejbuser` with password `12345678` and role `appCitas`. The instructions that I followed are:

> C:\wildfly-14.0.1.Final\bin>jboss-cli.bat
>   You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
>   [disconnected /] connect
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/filesystem-realm=proxyRealm:add(path=proxy-realm-users,relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir)
>   {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/filesystem-realm=proxyRealm:add-identity(identity=ejbuser)
>   {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/filesystem-realm=proxyRealm:set-password(identity=ejbuser,clear={password=12345678})
>   {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/filesystem-realm=proxyRealm:add-identity-attribute(identity=ejbuser,name=Roles,value=["guest", "appCitas"])
>   {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/simple-role-decoder=from-roles-attribute:add(attribute=Roles)
>   {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/security-domain=proxySD:add(default-realm=proxyRealm,permission-mapper=default-permission-mapper,realms=[{realm=proxyRealm,role-decoder=from-roles-attribute},{realm=local}])
>   {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/sasl-authentication-factory=proxy-application-sasl-autentication:add(mechanism-configurations=[{mechanism-name=JBOSS-LOCAL-USER,realm-mapper=local},{mechanism-name=DIGEST-MD5,mechanism-realm-configurations=[{realm-name=proxyRealm}]},{mechanism-name=BASIC,mechanism-realm-configurations=[{realm-name=proxyRealm}]}],sasl-server-factory=configured,security-domain=proxySD)
>   {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=ejb3/application-security-domain=other:add(security-domain=proxySD)
>   {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=remoting/http-connector=http-remoting-connector:write-attribute(name=sasl-authentication-factory,value=proxy-application-sasl-autentication)
>   {
>       "outcome" => "success",
>       "response-headers" => {
>           "operation-requires-reload" => true,
>           "process-state" => "reload-required"
>       }
>   }

In mi EJB, I have

```
@WebService(
  endpointInterface = "es.ssib.otic.test.prototipoEjbCitas.ApiCitasPublico",
  name = "ApiCitasEjb")
@RolesAllowed("apiCitas")
@Stateless
public class ApiCitasPublicoImpl
    implements ApiCitasPublico {

    @Override
    public @XmlElement(name = "pacienteCitaResponse", required = true) PacienteCitaResponse getPacienteCita(
        @WebParam(name = "datosSolicitante") @XmlElement(required = true) IdPeticion idPaciente) {
   ...
}
```

And my `jboss-app.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-app>
   <security-domain>other</security-domain>
</jboss-app>
```

The ear deploys correctly and it does not show any log problem, yet I try to access a method from SoapUI and I add a Basic Authentication, with:

- username: ejbuser
- password: 12345678
- Domain: I have tried with other, proxySD, proxyRealm and leaving it blank
- Pre-emptive auth: I have combined all of the above values of "Domain" with both "Use-global-preference" and "Authenticate pre-emptively".

In all cases, I get a

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
       <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
       <faultstring>WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public es.ssib.otic.test.prototipoEjbCitas.beans.PacienteCitaResponse es.ssib.otic.test.prototipoEjbCitas.impl.ApiCitasPublicoImpl.getPacienteCita(es.ssib.otic.test.prototipoEjbCitas.beans.IdPeticion) of bean: ApiCitasPublicoImpl is not allowed</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If I remove the security configuration, I can access through SoapUI with no problems.

Working with WildFly 14.0.0.1 Final.

Note: This question is somewhat related to [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075288/security-domain-not-found-in-wildfly-elytron), but since I have reinstalled the wildfly and I have followed step by step the above mentioned tutorial, I think it is better to post it as a separate question.

---

#### Update

Following the lead of @fjuma's answer, I have configured the following:

> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/http-authentication-factory=proxy-application-http-authentication:add(http-server-mechanism-factory=global,security-domain=proxySD,mechanism-configurations=[{mechanism-name=BASIC,mechanims-realm-configuration=[{realm-name=proxyAD}]}])
>   {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=undertow/application-security-domain=proxyAD:add(http-authentication-factory=proxy-application-http-authentication)
>   {"outcome" => "success"}

And changed the value of `security-domain` in `jboss-app.xml` to `proxyAD`, I get an error deploying the ear:

> {
>       "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.proxyAD"],
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>           "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"prototipoEarCitas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"prototipoEjbCitas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".component.ApiCitasPublicoImpl.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.proxyAD]",
>           "jboss.ws.endpoint.\"prototipoEarCitas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"prototipoEjbCitas-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".ApiCitasPublicoImpl is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.proxyAD]"
>       ]
>   }

Comment: Were you able to resolve the last issue `WFLYCTL0412`? I'm seeing the same error after correctly configuring elytron/undertow/ejb security domains. It works if I remove `@WebService` annotation. Class is loaded as a normal EJB, but I see the `WFLYCTL0412` as soon as I add `@WebService` annotation.

Comment: After seeing your comment on naming 3 security domains with same name, I tried it and it works now. Its strange that its needed only for `@WebService`, normal EJBs and Servlets work with security domains with different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to note:

- To make use of HTTP Basic authentication, an Elytron `http-authentication-factory` is needed. Documentation on how to configure this can be found [here](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/_elytron/Using_the_Elytron_Subsystem.adoc#configure-an-http-authentication-factory).
- When using HTTP Basic authentication, an `application-security-domain` mapping also needs to be added in the Undertow subsystem. See https://developer.jboss.org/thread/276445 for more details related to this when using webservices.

---

###Update by the OP:

This is the final minimal set of commands to configure EJBs access through WS (tested on a clean, brand new Wildfly 14.0.1. Final):

> C:\wildfly-14.0.1.Final\bin>jboss-cli.bat
> You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or '
> help' for the list of supported commands.
> [disconnected /] connect
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/properties-realm=proxyRealm:add(groups-attribute=groups,groups-properties={path=proxy-roles.properties,relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir},users-properties={path=proxy-users.properties,relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir,plain-text=true})
> {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/security-domain=proxySD:add(realms=[{realm=proxyRealm,role-decoder=groups-to-roles}],default-realm=proxyRealm,permission-mapper=default-permission-mapper)
> {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/http-authentication-factory=proxy-http-auth:add(http-server-mechanism-factory=global,security-domain=proxySD,mechanism-configurations=[{mechanism-name=BASIC,mechanism-realm-configurations=[{realm-name=proxyRealm}]}]
> {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=undertow/application-security-domain=proxySD:add(http-authentication-factory=proxy-http-auth)
> {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=elytron/sasl-authentication-factory=proxy-app-sasl-auth:add(mechanism-configurations=[{mechanism-name=JBOSS-LOCAL-USER,realm-mapper=local},{mechanism-name=BASIC,mechanism-realm-configurations=[{realm-name=proxyRealm}]}],sasl-server-factory=configured,security-domain=proxySD)
> {"outcome" => "success"}
>
> [standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=ejb3/application-security-domain=proxySD:add(security-domain=proxySD)
> {"outcome" => "success"}

Notes:

1. As you may have noticed, I switched from a FileSystem realm to a Properties realm. This is not related to the issue, it is just that it made easier to debug.
2. Elytron's security domain (defined at the 3rd command), Undertow's application security domain (defined at the 4th command) and EJB's application-security-domain (defined at the 6th command) have all the same name `proxySD`. That the **name is the same in all three subsystems is important, and bad things can happen if they have different names** (I have not tried out all the combinations).
3. WS based on EJBs must be invoked with "authenticate pre-emptively", sending the authentication data in the first request without being prompted by the server. WS based on POJOs in a war use the authentication system for web pages, so there is no need to authentica pre-emptively.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added some step on the basis of your link, yet it does not work (I have added the details as an update to my question, as they are somewhat long). It seems that the domain defined in `jboss-app.xml` must be the `Elytron` domain, not the `Undertow` one.

Comment: Of, I finally got it, sorry for the long wait but I had also an issue with WS with POJOs accepting the "normal" Basic auth (send the auth info only when requested by the server) vs WS with EJBs which fail if you do not send the auth info preemptively. I am going to adapt your answer with the full command set that I have ended using up, as SO discourages link-only answers.