# EJBs access through WS with mutual SSL authentication

Tags: ssl, ejb, wildfly, ws

The context of my question is:

[Configuring security to access EJB through WS -- WFLYEJB0364 Connection rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113423/configuring-security-to-access-ejb-through-ws-wflyejb0364-connection-rejected/54888631#54888631)

I configured Wildfly for SSL secured EJBs with Elytron following the tutorials:

How to configure SSL/HTTPS on WildFly:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/complete-tutorial-for-configuring-ssl-https-on-wildfly

and

SSL secured EJBs with Elytron

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/ssl-secured-ejb-with-elytron

in order to perform mutual SSL authentication, but with no success. How can I configure EJBs access through WS with mutual SSL authentication?

Comment: Were there some errors you've received? Can you provide any more information?

Comment: I completed the elytron configuration with success for security domain, keystore, truststore, I developed an EJB3 exposed as webservice that works with basic authentication, but now with SSL does not works. In SOAP UI, after client certificate configuration, If I make a call I have always the error javax.ejb.EJBAccessException in the server log. Nothing related to SSL communication. I'm trying to understand the mutual SSL authentication for an Ejb exposed as Web Service in Wildfly 15.